# Black screen when running game in virtualbox on linux

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtualbox, linux-mint, gaming

After installing the virthualbox 4.2 in linux mint and installing Windows XP in virtualbox (Testing in windows 7 shows the same problem)

When I try to run a game (like Red Alert 2), it shows me a black screen while the running game however I still hear the game sounds...

I modified the display settings in virtualbox to the following:

```
video memory: 64 MB
Enable 3D Acceleration
Enable 2D Video Acceleration
```

However I a black screen still appears when you play the game

My operating system:

```
Linux mint release 1 (debian)
Kernel linux 3.2.0-2-amd64
Memory: 2.0 GiB
CPU core 2 Duo T5800 @ 2.00Ghz
```

Comment: Yeah, guest os is windows xp, and host is linux mint

Comment: I edited the question to make it easier to understand and more obvious which OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Update your video card driver for both host and guest. Make sure that you have the latest updates for both your OS(s) as well. Then it should work just fine.